# Auto Number field

Tags: visualforce, auto-number

I want to update the name field of newly inserted record with auto number field value.But auto number field is showing as null.But when I see the account record I could see the value of auto number field value on account page.

```
public PageReference MakeAnonymous(){
Account acc = new Account(Name='Anon');
insert acc;
system.debug('account number..'+ acc.Auto_Number__c);
acc.Name = acc.Name + '-'+ acc.Auto_Number__c;
update acc;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value of auto_number__c is set when you insert the record. You would need to query the database to see what the value is.

For example

```
public PageReference MakeAnonymous(){
Account acc = new Account(Name='Anon');
insert acc;
acc = [select auto_number__c, name from account where id = :acc.id];
system.debug('account number..'+ acc.Auto_Number__c);
acc.Name = acc.Name + '-'+ acc.Auto_Number__c;
update acc;
}
```

Comment: +1 but I'd say it in a bit more generic way - only `Id` value returns when you insert a record. It's your job to fetch back any values that were set on the database level (autonumbers, which record type was selected, what values were set by specifying a default val. on a field, what was set using workflows or triggers, who is the new record owner...)

Comment: Good point @eyescream